# How can i use TLS with IOT IBM?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I have already worked with IOT MQTT protocol but now i want to work with IBM IOT MQTT with TLS and i want to publish and subscribe messages using python 3.7 and paho-mqtt library please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the libraries from here: https://ibm-watson-iot.github.io/iot-python/

The connection is secured with TLS by default by the libs.